# Php create Dynamic Xml in foreach

Tags: php, xml, oop, foreach

I built an basic xml class (using simple xml), so far I built simple xml nodes.

Now I want to create a function in which generate a specific number of nodes in a foreach, which I specify in the parameter.

it looks like this now:

```
class Xml
{

    private $data = "";

    protected $xml = "";
    protected $xmlManager = "";
    protected $menus = "";
    protected $xmlMenus = "";

    public function __construct($data = [])
    {
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->xml  = new \SimpleXmlElement('<test></test>');
        $this->setMenus();
        return $this->xml;
    }
    private function setMenus()
    {
        $this->xmlMenus = $this->xmlManager->addChild('menus');
    }

    public function setMenuNode($parameter)
    {
        $this->data->menu = []
        foreach ($this->data->menus as $menuKey => $menuValue)
        {
            $this->xmlMenu = $this->xmlMenus->addChild('menu');
            $menueValue->addAttribute($param1, $param2, $param3);
            $menueValue->addAttribute($param1, $param2, $param3);
        }

    }

}
```

Later on I want to call it like this

```
Xml->setMenuNode($param1, $param2, $param3);
```

Which should create 3 menu nodes.

My xml should look like this later on.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <menus>
      <menu id="1" entry="title">
        ...
      </menu>
      <menu id="2" entry="title2">
        ...
      </menu>
      <menu id="3" entry="title2">
        ...
      </menu>
    </menus>
</dvd>
```

I am not quiet sure how to manager this in a good way.

Comment: You can not return a value from the constructor.

Comment: what exactly do you mean

Comment: Before you removed the constructor you called `return $this->xml;` in it. That does not work. Now without the constructor, your properties are all empty strings, but used as objects.

Comment: I am building an Object of Xml and calling it like this `echo "<pre>".print_r($xml,true)."</pre>";` just to see the results, but Do you know how to fix my problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This are two jobs, so you should split it into two classes. For a loose dependency define an interface. The menu and the items need to be append itself to their parent.

I use DOM because SimpleXMLElement does not support an empty XML document. This solution would work with SimpleXML, too. But only with an additional outer XML element node.

### Interface

This is a contract, so you should define an interface for it.

```
interface DOMAppendable {
  public function appendTo(\DOMNode $parent);
}
```

### Item Class

For a single item implement the interface:

```
class MenuItem implements DOMAppendable {

  private $_id = '';
  private $_title = '';

  public function __construct($id, $title) {
    $this->_id = $id;
    $this->_title = $title;
  }

  public function appendTo(\DOMNode $parent) {
    $document = $parent->ownerDocument ?: $parent;
    $item = $parent->appendChild($document->createElement('menu'));
    $item->setAttribute('id', $this->_id);
    $item->setAttribute('title', $this->_title);
  }
}
```

The constructor stores the data into private properties. The method from the interface appends the nodes to the provided parent. The menu items contain more data, have subitems. As long as they implement the interface it will still work.

### Menu/List Class

A class for the menu itself stores added menu items into an array property. It implements the interface, too. (So it can be appended to another menu). Implementing __toString() allows to cast the menu into a string.

```
class Menu implements DOMAppendable {

  private $_items = [];

  public function add(\DOMAppendable $item) {
    foreach (func_get_args() as $item) {
      if (!($item instanceOf DOMAppendable)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Invalid menu item.");
      }
      $this->_items[] = $item;   
    }
  }

  public function appendTo(\DOMNode $parent) {
    $document = $parent->ownerDocument ?: $parent;
    $menu = $parent->appendChild($document->createElement('menus'));
    foreach ($this->_items as $item) {
      $item->appendTo($menu);
    }
  }

  public function __toString() {
    $document = new \DOMDocument();
    $document->formatOutput = TRUE;
    $this->appendTo($document);
    return $document->saveXml();
  }
}
```

### Use

With that you can create the menu using the new classes.

```
$menu = new Menu();
$menu->add(
  new MenuItem(1, 'title1'),
  new MenuItem(2, 'title2'),
  new MenuItem(3, 'title3')
);

echo $menu;
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<menus>
  <menu id="1" title="title1"/>
  <menu id="2" title="title2"/>
  <menu id="3" title="title3"/>
</menus>
```

The interface allows to use different menu item classes, even a menu can be an item:

```
$menu = new Menu();
$menu->add(
  new MenuItem(1, 'title1'),
  new MenuItem(2, 'title2')
);
$subMenu = new Menu();
$subMenu->add(new MenuItem(3.1, 'title3.1'));
$menu->add($subMenu);

echo $menu;
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<menus>
  <menu id="1" title="title1"/>
  <menu id="2" title="title2"/>
  <menus>
    <menu id="3.1" title="title3.1"/>
  </menus>
</menus>
```

### PHP >= 5.6

PHP 5.6 and later support the new variadics syntax. This allows to remove the `func_get_args()` call and simplify the `Menu::add()` method.

```
class Menu implements DOMAppendable {

  private $_items = [];

  public function add(\DOMAppendable ...$items) {
    foreach ($items as $item) {
      $this->_items[] = $item;   
    }
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you described you would get (PHP 5.6):

```
function setMenuNode(...$parameters)
{
  foreach ($parameters as $parameter) {
    $this->xmlMenu = $this->xmlMenus->addChild('menu');
    $menueValue->addAttribute('id', $parameter);
    $menueValue->addAttribute('entry', 'title' . $parameter);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to make the title name dynamic as well how would you manage that?

Comment: Depends on what you set in a parameter.

Comment: Good luck, with the splat operator (three dots before $parameters) you can pass a dynamic number of arguments to your function: 
Xml->setMenuNode($param1, $param2, $param3, $param4, etc);

Comment: Too bad I am sitting on 5.5 :) Thanks anyway